# Running Process as Unprivileged User

Tags: linux, background, process

On Linux system, how does one run a process as a different, unprivileged user (like how lighttpd is run by www-data in the default setup)?

I've been using `su $user; $command &` over ssh, but those processes get killed when I logout.

If it makes any difference, I'm using a default Ubuntu setup on EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
su $other_user -c 'nohup sleep 600 &'
```

Comment: Brilliant, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

```
nohup $command  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

or

```
command </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null  &; disown
```